# Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 11.0.3436.0 download

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

Where can I download SQL Server Reporting Services Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 11.0.3436.0?

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted based on a version compatibility error. I was trying to open a report solution that was originally created on VS2012. However, I did not have SSDT 2012 version installed. Below is the link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843